# How do I change from Discord.py async to rewrite while using Heroku?

Tags: python, asynchronous, heroku, discord, discord.py

I need some assistance with migrating with Heroku as I've added `git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite#egg=discord.py[voice]` into my requirements.txt file and I'm confused as when I do that, it doesn't change to rewrite, even if I still import discord. I have changed all my code to rewrite, like for example: `bot.say` to `ctx.send`. All of that is done, but when I place `git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite#egg=discord.py[voice]` into my requirements.txt file, it still thinks it's async. Please help as I tried so much just to get this working and I can't seem to find a way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could we see your `full requirements.txt`?  I know `git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite` is the right way to do it without voice, so you might try `git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite[voice]`

Answer (score 1):

LOL wait woops I just had to add `yarl<1.2` to requirements.txt